# Train a model using a merged dataset consisted of values obtained from two different methods

Tags: machine-learning, data-preprocessing

I have 100 samples and I performed a certain analysis which resulted in approx. 60 features with measures ranging between 0 and 1 (after a preprocessing round).

For the same 100 samples, I was given measures from another analysis (a method completely uncorrelated to my analysis) which resulted in 4 features with measures ranging between -4 and 4 (after preprocessing and log2 transform).

The question is: my task is to merge this two measurements and train ML models for classification. How can I deal with features with different scales and variance? Also, we are considering adding binary features to the dataset.

Each dataset had its separate preprocessing, but I'm not sure if a simple merge and training is appropriate, is there any final preprocessing to be done?

I would be grateful for any paper recomendations regarding this subject.